# PayPal Payment Page Hangs When Paying By Credit Card

Tags: paypal, checkout

We have a working integration with PayPal which has been working for years.
Today we tried to checkout a product and pay by credit card via PayPal but after successful completion of the credit card form the "Loading" icon displays but the page just hangs forever. I checked the PayPal account and the transaction was not made.
This is a test product that I used in the checkout process: http://www.ajhockey.com/catalog/item/6945045/9451792.htm
Anyone else having this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an aggressive popup blocker, it might the be cause of the problem. Better Popup Blocker for Chrome was causing me this issue.